# Weird Memory Management Occurrence iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

For some reason in my below code, the `replies` array is `NSLogging` the correct description, but the `comment.replies` array is `NSLogging` null.

I immediately presumed that this was due to a memory management issue within my code, but I don't believe that that is true.

Please can you tell me why this is occurring?

```
- (TBComment *) dictionaryToComment:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    TBComment *comment = [[TBComment alloc] init];
    [comment setBody:[dict objectForKey:@"body"]];
    [comment setCommentID:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];
    [comment setCreated_at:[dict objectForKey:@"created_at"]];
    [comment setUpdated_at:[dict objectForKey:@"updated_at"]];
    [comment setUser:[self dictionaryToUser:[dict objectForKey:@"user"]]];
    NSMutableArray *replies = nil;
    if ([[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"replies"]) {
        replies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *reply in [dict objectForKey:@"replies"]) {
            NSLog(@"in");
            [replies addObject:[self dictionaryToComment:reply]];
        }
    }
    if (replies != nil) {
        [comment setReplies:replies];
        NSLog(@"COMMENT REPLIES = %@", comment.replies);
        NSLog(@"REPLIES = %@", replies);
        [replies release];
    }
    return [comment autorelease];
}
```

Console ->

```
2011-11-30 21:25:14.980 Timbrr[2379:f803] in
2011-11-30 21:25:14.980 Timbrr[2379:f803] COMMENT REPLIES = (null)
2011-11-30 21:25:14.980 Timbrr[2379:f803] REPLIES = (
    "<TBComment: 0x68dbeb0>"
)


- (void) setReplies:(NSArray *)_replies {
    hasReplies = (_replies == nil ? NO : ([_replies count] == 0 ? NO : YES));
    //replies is synthesised
}
```

Comment: Also, post the code for `setReplies:` in your `TBComment` class, if you're not using a synthesized setter.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Is comment.replies declared as "strong"?

Comment: I would assume that the presence of `release` and `autorelease` in his code suggest he's not using ARC. Also, I don't think improper retaining of the `replies` array would result it in being `nil`.

Comment: I am not using ARC. `replies` is declared as (nonatomic, retain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that either `comment` is `nil` (though this would require explicit `nil`-returning code in `TBComment`, which is possible, but unusual), or that `-replies` or `-setReplies:` are incorrectly implemented. Do you have custom implementations for those?

Your implementation of `setReplies:` never sets `_replies`.

Comment: I do have a custom implementation for -setReplies:. I have updated the post with code for doing so.

Answer (score 7):

After seeing your implementation of `setReplies:`, I don't think you quite understand how `@synthesize` works.

`@synthesize replies;` will generate a getter and a setter for this instance variable. **BUT** since you're overriding it (and improperly) the synthesized setter is being tossed aside. (In fact, no setter is being created for you at all, since you wrote one yourself.)

The root issue is that in your implementation of `setReplies:`, you're not actually assigning the value of your `replies` instance variable to the parameter of the setter.

What I think you want is:

```
- (void) setReplies:(NSArray *)_replies {
    hasReplies = (_replies == nil ? NO : ([_replies count] == 0 ? NO : YES));
    // How is your ivar defined in the header file? As _replies, or replies?
    if (replies != _replies) {
        [replies release];
        replies = [_replies retain];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks craig, +1. I appreciate this answer more than @Rob Napier's, as it describes, in more detail, the reasoning behind my misinterpretation and the answer. However, I have accepted his answer merely as it was first and tells me why the `replies` variable was nil.

Answer (score 0):

The `replies` property is never set - when you define `setReplies:`, the `@synthesize` directive does not create any setter method.